# Using Swift 5 library with XCode 10.3 or Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have a generic question about how could I build a library with XCode 11/swift 5 which is compatible with XCode 10.3/Swift 4.2.

With some investigation these are my finding

- **XCFramwork** - Not compatible with XCode 10.3
- **Cocoapods**- If built with swift 5 and Xcode 11 it wont be compatible, even if you force the swift version in pod file, most of
  the time it will fail
  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551244/using-swift-5-libraries-in-a-swift-4-project]
- **Framework** - If built with swift 5 and Xcode 11 it wont be compatible

Am I missing something here or is there any suggestions for me to build the library in a way it will support XCode 10.3

Thank you for the help !

Comment: Maybe a static library would help?

Comment: Is it possible to create a static library with XCode 11 with backward compatibility ?

Comment: Also Isn't static library have the same limitation of other methods of compiling swift version.